# Is there any purpose built tool I can use to grab and pull a low gauge a wire through 30+ feet of interstitial space?

Tags: wiring

I would like to have a 220vac outlet in my garage. Problem is, the fusebox is in a finished basement about 35 feet from the garage. I don't have permission from my wife to cut a channel in the ceiling (honestly this is probably for the best).

I can push the wire up from the fusebox to the interstitial space. I'm wondering if there is some sort of hook-on-a-pole I can push through the interstitial space from the garage and grab the wire. A literal hook wouldn't work I think, I'd need it to actually grab the wire, but I'm not certain what to use. Is there a tool I could use for this? For reference there is a simplified diagram below.

[image]

Comment: *interstice* "an intervening space, especially a very small one." - "the space between cells in a tissue." ... You a doctor or somethn? - Don't need a channel but you need a hole every 4~8' or where ever it binds, and to drill holes through blocking if there is any. There's always something.... *Drywall is the enemy.* - It's also supposed to be, you know, attached to hangers or through bespoke holes, but who's counting.

Comment: Which way do the joists run? If they are perpendicular to your proposed run, that's gonna make for a tough pull...

Comment: pulling wire through drop ceilings designed for utilities (interstitial space) where you don't have to worry about the ceiling assembly is pretty easy.  How must space from the ceiling assembly do you have?  Commercial building they often have 2' and you can just use a fish tape and push it out until you get to the wall.  For the stud bay in the wall I'd just pop up into the space and drill down through the top plate and use a plumbers chain to get to the fuse box ( you should get breakers - surprised you still have fuses? ) and then pull the wire up into the space.

Comment: IMO the OP's first problem here is going to be getting whatever (wire, string, etc.) from the fusebox up through the top plate.  I think at least *one* hole will need to be cut in the ceiling.

Answer (score 7):

I have used these [Pull rods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08LG1C3DF) to pull and fish all types of wires and even PEX through many spaces.

Comment: Looks much easier than pushing fish tape. Nice!

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Fish rods should be great here. I've had good luck using them to pull through ENT as well, and advise OP to do that because then it only has to be done once. Assuming this is for EV charging, 3/4" ENT with THHN in it will let you get all the way up to a 60A circuit, enough to easily let you put in two EVSEs in the future.

Answer (score 4):

##### Fishing for wire - basic technique

Tie a loop in the end of a reasonably light-weight but strong string (mason's line or similar). The loop should be maybe 3/4" diameter. Raise the loop into the interstitial space above the fuse box -- one way of doing this is to loosely tape the string to the wire, or a fish rod, or other semi-rigid object.

At the garage end install a hook accessory on the tip of a fish/pull rod. Feed that into the interstitial space, adding additional rods as needed, until the hook can reach the looped string. Use the hook to grab the loop and pull the string back to you.

Once the string is in place, tie and tape it to the cable and use the string to pull the cable through.

##### Tips and tricks

- If the cable to be installed is light enough, you may be able to form a loop with the wire itself and hook that directly rather than using the string.
- If you can't see the loop clearly (perhaps the distance is too great, poorly lit, or there are obstructions like ductwork, plumbing, or insulation) then try attaching a bore scope camera to the fish rod. I have one that has a 30 foot USB cable; wireless models are also available. Position and tape the camera to the fish rod so that you have a good view of the hook.

Comment: Given this is a hefty cable, might want to use the string to pull in a rope. Hollow-braided rope is particularly handy, because if you push on the end, you can expand it to go over the end of the cable (like a steel-cable cable grip does) and then as you pull the rope grabs the cable tighter. Or you could tie any strong rope to a steel cable grip, but that's one more thing to buy for a one-off job.